# How can i processing only 2 frame per second ?How can I exit while loop in c or c++?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, visual-studio-2012, image-processing

when i run this code and press Esc key on keyboard i can not exit while loop.
   i use same code in another program (in main() function) and exit from while loop.
i do not use below code in main() function.it is recall by function that it used in main().
i want to stop processing capture from video and do other work  , i do not  want to close program completely.i want to only processing 2 frame per second,how i can do it?
(when capture frame from video or cam in opencv 2.4.6,windows7,vs2012)
please help me.

```
void Demo::processVideo()
{
VideoCapture cap(this->videofile.c_str());
cout<<"Loading classifier...."<<endl;
MultiTrain mt;
mt.loadModel(("f:\dataset/eye_svm_model.xml"));
int fps=(int) cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
if(!cap.isOpened())
{
cout<<"problems with avi file"<<endl;
}
else
{
cout<<"Processing video...."<<endl;
Mat frame;
int k = 0,key1=0;
while(1)
{
//char c = WaitKey(15);
// if( c == 27 ) break;
cap>>frame;
int res = (int)mt.getPrediction(frame);
cout<<"Prediction for frame #"<<k<<" => "<<res<<endl;
this->predictions.push_back(res);
k++;
}
cap.release();
}

}
```

Comment: please use  opencv's c++ api, not the outdated c one.

Comment: not unless you change to c++.

Comment: i change to c++ please help me.

Comment: for 2 fps, you need to wait 500 ms. but waitKey only works, if there is a highgui window (it's waiting for keypresses in that window). if you never do namedWindow, or imshow() (maybe you got your own gui), waitKey() will never find anything.

Comment: As I have been told,i want first get frames , do processing , save results and then show frames with results.How i can processing 2 frame per second and stop processing anytime by press a key ?

Comment: again, waitKey can only work, if a highgui window is active at the same time , and if you press a key, while that window has focus.

Comment: i do not want to use only waitkey() for stop processing,i want to use any code for stop processing.i do not use waitkey().

Answer (score 0):

It should be a type conversion problem since the function prototype is  `int cvWaitKey(int)`
Try the following into the loop, and press ESC for exit the program.

```
char c = cvWaitKey(15);
if( c == 27 ) break;
```

Comment: hi eric.i use your suggested code but i can not stop while loop.

Comment: I try cvWaitKey(0) but i can not stop while loop

Comment: Do you display the video frames in a cvWindow?

Comment: i want to capture from video and processing these frames and then show results on window in another function,in this function i want to grab frame from video file until i press Esc key.afther i press Esc key i show result in the another function

Answer (score 0):

If you want precise time control or frame rate control, you can count clock ticks. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) for details with example.
Good luck and happy coding.